# create a modal that is animated via jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-animate, modal-dialog

I'd like to create a customizable jQuery modal that is animated in and out (css color changes + fade in and out) that is triggered by a click on the main html page. I know how to pass option variables into a jquery plugin, but I am not sure how to animate within the plugin. Eg: with inline jquery you can just say:

`<script>
$("#modal").animate({color: 'red', width: 300}).fadeIn('fast');
</script>`

How would I be able to make these same changes within a plugin? Here is a chunk of the code (was trying to use Jeff Ways' jQuery plugin tutorial:

```
var mybigmodal= {
        init: function( options, elem) {
            var self = this;

            self.elem = elem;
            self.$elem = $( elem );

           if ( typeof options === 'string') {
                var w = 400;
                var h = 600;
           } else {
                //object was passed
                self.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.mymodal.options, options)

          }

          self.mshow();
        },

        mshow: function() { //show the modal via animation?


          $('#lightbox-pane').fadeIn(50).animate({
              width: 50}, 150).animate({
                  width: 100},200);
          }
        }; 
    });
```

I don't need someone to code this for me, I just would like to know what I'm doing wrong in order to make these same animations happen that are so simple while inline..

*I'd really like to enable the user to be able to use options like custom width or color as well.*

(I know this maybe a noob basic question, but any help would be appreciated!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this inside your plugin code:

First extend your plugin options as

```
var options = $.extend({
            height : "250",
            width : "500",
            color: "red",
            title:"Modal Box Demo",
            description: "Example of how to create a modal box.",
            top: "20%",
            left: "35%",

        },prop);


       $('#modal').animate({top:'toggle'},80);
```